# Does WKWebview still have the 1024*1024*3 / 6.5Mb limit for images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

On iOS, the UIWebview has hard-coded limitation of 1024*1024*3 in total decoded image size for a page, and/or 6.5Mb limit for total of all images (unless I am wrong or not exact).

I am a game developer that is struggling to make a hybrid app (2D game) for iOS8. It uses a very big background (about 10000px * 4000px), which I cannot break in smaller tiles without changing too much the game's look, gameplay and programming approach/logic. So I am looking at WKWebview since it already boosts the performance of my game, and since I have high hope that it would be the only solution available right now for non-native iOS apps to leverage or to get rid of those hard-coded image limitations. But it will still be useless if those specific constraints are not better than they were with UIWebview. So my main question is:

**Do you know if those constraints have been increased to higher values (or maybe even retrieved) with WKWebview?** Or we are still stuck with the same limitations as with UIWebview in that aspect?

Another useful information that I need and that is directly related to those constraints, **is if other media (like audio) are also adding up to the maximum quantity of download a webpage can load on Safari Mobile, on top of images?**

I have found no documentation about that anywhere. So I suppose nothing has changed, but I want to know if this is true or not before continuing in any direction with the development.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would tiling change your game?

Comment: You expect your users to download a 40 MP image? When they're on mobile?

Comment: This would not even work on desktop, I don't think texture dimensions supported by hardware are any larger than 8096px. Probably half of this on high end Apple device. You'll have to make tiles like normal people do.